# ffmpeg: AVI to FLV conversion doubles file size

Tags: ffmpeg, flv, filesize, avi

I convert AVI to FLV with ffmpeg using -sameq parameter (same quality):

```
ffmpeg -i test.avi -sameq -f flv sameq.flv
```

The resulting file has the same video and audio quality as the original, but it's more than twice the original file size:

```
84M sameq.flv
41M test.avi
```

Why does it happen?

Transcoder output:

```
ffmpeg version N-34750-g070d2d7, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov 12 2011 11:23:07 with gcc 4.6.1
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab
  libavutil    51. 24. 1 / 51. 24. 1
  libavcodec   53. 33. 0 / 53. 33. 0
  libavformat  53. 20. 0 / 53. 20. 0
  libavdevice  53.  4. 0 / 53.  4. 0
  libavfilter   2. 48. 0 /  2. 48. 0
  libswscale    2.  1. 0 /  2.  1. 0
  libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0
Input #0, avi, from 'test.avi':
  Duration: 00:06:30.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 866 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Advanced Real Time Simple Profile) (DIVX / 0x58564944), yuv420p, 400x300 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
[buffer @ 0xa247ae0] w:400 h:300 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/1000000 sar:1/1 sws_param:
Output #0, flv, to 'sameq.flv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf53.20.0
    Stream #0:0: Video: flv1 ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p, 400x300 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 1k tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg4 -> flv)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (mp3 -> libmp3lame)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 9742 fps=255 q=0.0 Lsize=   85074kB time=00:06:30.00 bitrate=1787.0kbits/s    
video:79163kB audio:5525kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.455568%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two thing comes to mind:

1. Compress a video without audio stream to eliminate the audio portion of this issue. BTW, the audio source is HALF the bitrate of the output, that increases the size a little. Use -ar and -ab switches to control the output.
2. Check out this article on [qscale vs quality](http://www.kilobitspersecond.com/2007/05/24/ffmpeg-quality-comparison/) using -qscale option. Add in the -b (bitrate) and -s (size) and tweak it to your needs.

When all fails, there are a few switches you can try from the [ffmpeg website](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) or try using the new [H.264 compression](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FFMPEG_An_Intermediate_Guide/h.264), the two pass option is recommended. Have fun compressing

Comment: Thanks! Great advice! But why it doubles in size is still not clear.

Comment: Original uses mpeg4, which typically has higher [compression ratio](http://www.kanecomputing.co.uk/pdfs/compression_ratio_rules_of_thumb.pdf) than non h.264 codecs, in your case flv default setting.

Answer (score 1):

its because of `-sameq`. It gives you a good quality but pay the price with a bigger file size.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding:

```
-qcomp 1.0
```

video quantizer scale compression ( VBR ) (default 0.5). Constant of ratecontrol equation. Recommended range for default rc_eq: 0.0-1.0

Comment: Same result. Quality and file size are the same.